# Toggle Class to select offer with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to make something and I try to figure out. I want to add a class only to the clicked div. If div number 1 is clicked and I click on div number 2, the class is removed from div1 and added to div2. Hope you understand.

here 's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVOGgd) illustrating my problem

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="AboApp">
<h3>NOS ABONNEMENTS</h3>
<div class="row db-padding-btm db-attached" ng-controller="AboCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="abos in abo">
        <div class="db-wrapper" ng-click="zone()">
            <div class="db-pricing-eleven db-bk-color-two" select-me="areaStatus">
                <div ng-class="{'price' : !areaStatus, 'price pop' : areaStatus}">
                    {{abos.tarif}}<sup>€</sup>
                    <small>par mois</small>
                </div>
                <div class="type">
                    {{abos.nom}}
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="icon-ok"></i>{{abos.communication}}</li>
                    <li><i class="icon-ok"></i>{{abos.vers}}</li>
                    <li><i class="icon-ok"></i>{{abos.zone}}</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="pricing-footer" ng-show="areaStatus">
                    <a href="#" class="btn db-button-color-square btn-lg">VALIDER</a>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("AboApp", []);

app.controller("AboCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.abo = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nom": "BAS PRIX",
                "tarif": "2.49",
                "communication": "2h de communication",
                "vers": "vers fixes et mobiles",
                "zone": "zone nationale"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nom": "NATIONAL",
                "tarif": "9.99",
                "communication": "t\u00e9l\u00e9phonie et SMS illimit\u00e9s",
                "vers": "vers fixes et mobiles",
                "zone": "zone nationale"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "nom": "EURO",
                "tarif": "19.99",
                "communication": "t\u00e9l\u00e9phonie et SMS illimit\u00e9s",
                "vers": "vers fixes et mobiles",
                "zone": "zone EURO"
            }
        ];

$scope.areaStatus = false;
$scope.zone = function() {
    $scope.areaStatus = !$scope.areaStatus;
}
});
app.directive("selectMe", function($animate) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.selectMe, function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            $animate.addClass(element, "popular")
        } else {
            $animate.removeClass(element, "popular")
        }
    })
}
});

app.controller("OptionsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://local.tel4g/options.json').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.options = data['data'];
    });
$scope.areaStatus = false;
});

app.controller("PhonesCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://local.tel4g/phones.json').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.phones = data['data'];
    });
$scope.areaStatus = false;
});
```

Comment: So basically it is the `radio` button type of behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, if I click a second time on the div, I want the class to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edit your code and when you select one it will add a class to that selected div and those other will not have that 'popular' class.

```
$scope.selected = { id: 0 };

ng-class="{'popular': selected.id === abos.id }"
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjbKQe?editors=101

Comment: Thanks Johnny, How can i remove the class if i click a second time to the selected div ?

Comment: I would create a setId method and compare if the current id is the same as clicked id. I have update the codepen. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

here is what i did, may be close enough what you are trying to do, it is having simple js and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="inner" onclick="functionName(event,this)">a</div>
      <div class="inner" onclick="functionName(event,this)">b</div>
      <div class="inner" onclick="functionName(event,this)">c</div>
      <div class="inner" onclick="functionName(event,this)">d</div>
      <div class="inner" onclick="functionName(event,this)">e</div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
function functionName(event, $this) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if ($($this)[0].className == "inner outer") {
      $($this)[0].className = "inner"
   } else {
      $($this)[0].className = "inner outer"
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < $('.inner').length; i++) {
      if ($('.inner')[i] != $($this)[0]) {
         $('.inner')[i].className = "inner";
      };
   }
}
   </script>
   <style type="text/css">
      .inner.outer{
      background: red;
      }
      .inner{
      background: yellow;
      }
   </style>
</html>
```